# How to publish paid android app

Tags: android, paypal, google-play

I need to publish priced app on google play, Then I need a Google payments merchant account. I checked the list of [merchant countries](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/3539140?hl=en&rd=1). But there are some countries that Location supports Google Play Developer registration, but does not support registration as a Google Payments merchant. Do you have any idea how to publish priced app located such country , and how to get handle payments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is no. To have paid apps you need to create account from supported country. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

If your country allows you to **open a bank account in a foreign country** then that would work. Google does care only where it can send the money. There are some countries that allow you open a bank account anywhere and still live in some other country.

If you cannot do that, you still could to monetize your free apps through ads.